# Can't download anything

Tags: wireless, networking, internet, downloads, usb-modem

When I try to install usb-modeswitch for making a mobile-broadband work, Ubuntu cannot download anything. Even when I tried to install Wine, it failed to connect to the internet even though I could surf websites.
Links for the image:

[image]

[image]

PS- This belonged to my sister and worked on a proxy server in IIT Delhi before giving it to me.
I went to Network Proxy->Direct Internet Connection so that I could use the wifi in my home.
Also, as you can see in the photos that the wifi is connected and I can use it to surf the net but it cannot download anything.
The Ubuntu is also unable to detect my Huawei USB Modem

Comment: Can you check the content of `/etc/apt/apt.conf` and `~/.bashrc` for a line like `Acquire::http::Proxy "http://repo.iitd.ernet.in";` or `http_proxy=http://repo.iitd.ernet.in` ? If they are there just remove them.

Comment: @Samik How do I check the contents of these? And there is no file or folder by the name of apt.conf, only apt.conf.d   I cannot locate ~/.bashrc also. The version of Ubutnu is 11.04

Comment: first check does `echo $http_proxy` give you anything. If it does then see `ls -a ~ | grep .bashrc` shows anything or not. Then open with `gedit ~/.bashrc`. Also check in `~/.profile`,`/etc/profile` and `/root/.bashrc`. Btw, the filenames starting with a `.` are hidden files(`ls -a` in terminal or __Ctrl__ + __H__ in file manager).

Comment: You have to locate a file which sets 'http_proxy' to something. You can use console command 'grep http_proxy' and add the files you want to search in after, like 'grep http_proxy ~/* ~/.* /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/*'. If there are any of those files that the text you search for, grep will write its name.